# GCP rsync fails from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gsutil

There is a shared directory(mounted path) which is used as source. And destination is one storage bucket. I have written the following cloud function which gets failed during execution. From command line, I am able to run the rsynch functionality.

```
def synch_data(request):
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["gsutil", "-m", "rsync", "/home/raw/abc_ftp_data", "gs://abc-raw"])
        print("PROC is instantiated ____")
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception Occure ...........",e)
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    return 'Success!'
```

The error I received as follows.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gsutil': 'gsutil'"
```

Can someone please help in this context.

Comment: Cloud Functions does not support `gsutil`. You will need to write code to copy files. There are many examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Google Cloud Function running in Python, it is recommended that you use the Google Cloud Storage Python API to upload files to the Cloud Storage Bucket.

The example can be found on [Cloud Storage > Uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) documentation.

This is an example and you can modify it according to your needs:

First add the Google Cloud Storage library in the `requirements.txt` file:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-storage
```

Then add this additional function and call it from your main function:

```
def copyToBucket(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    # Import the library
    from google.cloud import storage
    """ Uploads a file to the bucket. """
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

Then you can call the function from your main function like this:

`copyToBucket("[BUCKET_NAME]", "/PATH/TO/FILE/IN/SHARED/DIRECTORY/FILE_NAME.py", "NEW_FILE_NAME.py")`

Just modify the arguments passing to the function when calling it and your file will be uploaded to the desired Cloud Storage Bucket. I have tested the code and it worked for me.